# Conditional load of a partial in handlebars based on current url

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, partial

I'd like to load a handlebars partial, but only when the URL is '/foo', and load a different partial for '/bar'.

I know that this is always going to be a bit of a hack, and not really intended - but use to the project handlebars structure, it seems the most logical way of solving the problem I'm running into.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming

- jquery is included
- your template files are in the same folder
- your template files have the names "foo.bs" & "bar.hbs"

code

```
function loadTemplate(templateName) {
    $.get(templateName + '.hbs', function (data) {
        var template = Handlebars.compile(data);
        $(body).html(template(jsonData));
    }, 'html');
}

if (window.location.pathname.search('bar') !== -1) {
    loadTemplate('bar');
}
if (window.location.pathname.search('foo !== -1) {
    loadTemplate('foo');
}
```